# Xcode File was built for unsupported file format

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, terminal, architecture

I am trying to compile some code where a file is being read in from the command line. I am entering `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp buglog.txt` into terminal in macOS. I wrote the .h and .cpp files in Xcode, when I compile this way, I get the error `ld: warning: ignoring file buglog.txt, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x62 0x31 0x31 0x34 0x33 0x2C 0x52 0x65 0x73 0x6F 0x6C 0x76 0x65 0x64 0x2C 0x53 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): buglog.txt` Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: What is `buglog.txt`? Why are you trying to build with a (non-code?) text file?

Comment: `ld` is describing the 16-byte string "b1143,Resolved,S".  Definitely not what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simply not to pass `buglog.txt` to the compiler.